# How to write correct JSON file in C#?

Tags: c#

I need to write the following data into a text file using JSON format in C#. The brackets are important for it to be valid JSON format.

```
    {
      "id": 1,
      "houseattributes": [
        {
          "example_type": "big",
          "examplevalue": "black"
        },
        {
          "example_type": "small",
          "examplevalue": "white"
        },
        {
          "example_type": "very big",
          "examplevalue": "pink"
        },
       ...........
      ],
      "description": "some description..",
      "image": "image url...",
      "name": "house name...",
      "edition": 1
    }
```

With this Class i read the input Json but its in a wrong format and i must modify to the correct valid Json... and i must manually(code) adding the description + image url to the parsed Json.

```
    public class Houseattribute
    {
        public string example_type { get; set; }
        public string examplevalue { get; set; }
    }

    public class Root
    {
        public string name { get; set; }
        public int edition { get; set; }
        public List<Houseattribute> houseattributes { get; set; }
    }
```

how can i get the correct output json?

Input Json:

```
{
  "houseattributes": [
    {
      "example_type": "big",
      "examplevalue": "black"
    },
    {
      "example_type": "small",
      "examplevalue": "white"
    },
    {
      "example_type": "very big",
      "examplevalue": "pink"
    },
   .........
  ],
  "edition": 1,
  "name": "house name..."
}
```

Comment: I don't understand. What is wrong with the models you currently have, other than needing to add properties for `description` and `image`?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar the Input Json have not the same Format like my wanted Output. And i dont know how to Serialize Correct for the right Output :/

Comment: It looks like the same format other than needing a few extra properties? Why not just make a model with those extra properties, deserialize to that, fill in the blanks, and then re-serialize the model?

Comment: So are you trying to output the following json into text file using c# ?

Comment: @DiplomacyNotWar i added the Input Json, its a bit different like the Output.

Comment: @Sameh Yes, i added the Input Json, to see what i mean with "some stuff missing".

Comment: which json do you want to generate , the first one or the second one? your terms input and output are very confusing

Comment: @pm100 i want to generate the first one.

Comment: What i understood from your comments is when you serialize your class it doesn't generate the json in the exact output as you were expecting , like fields names are different , you need to work a little bit on your question description

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your model to include the extra properties:

```
public class Houseattribute
{
    public string example_type { get; set; }
    public string examplevalue { get; set; }
}

public class Root
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public string description { get; set; }
    public string image { get; set; }
    public int edition { get; set; }
    public List<Houseattribute> houseattributes { get; set; }
}
```

And then deserialize your JSON to the model, fill in the additional properties, and reserialize it. Example with JSON.NET:

```cs
Root obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(inputJson);
obj.id = 5;
obj.description = "Test";
obj.image = "https://www.example.com/images/myimage.jpg";
string outputJson = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj);
```

Note that I'd suggest updating your properties to follow the naming conventions used by Microsoft (TitleCase). You can decorate the properties with `[JsonPropery("name")]` (attributes with the same name exist in JSON.NET and System.Text.Json) to ensure they serialize correctly:

```cs
public class HouseAttribute
{
    [JsonProperty("example_type")]
    public string ExampleType { get; set; }
(etc.)
```

Answer (score 0):

just add the additonal fields to the class

```
public class Root
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int edition { get; set; }
    public List<Houseattribute> houseattributes { get; set; }
    public string image {get;set;}
    public string description {get;set;}
}
```

people are confused by the question becuase you seemed to be able to work out how to add 2 of the fields, but not the missing two